# Piecewise regression / Change point detection - Python

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, piecewise

I am trying to identify the change point of the data. The pictures below show the result i am getting and what i intend to do. Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

I have applied 2 methods; using pwlf library and numpy piecewise for piecewise regression.

Result:
[Result of both codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtLCf.jpg)

What i want 1:
[What i want 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK11O.png)
What i want 2:
[What i want 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkRHu.gif)

Code:

```
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(n3.Lufttemperatur)

y = np.array(n3.id030_1)


x= x.astype(np.float)
y = y.astype(np.float)

print (x.dtype)
print (y.dtype)


def piecewise_linear(x, x0, y0, k1, k2):
   return np.piecewise(x, [x < x0], [lambda x:k1*x + y0-k1*x0, lambda x:k2*x + y0-k2*x0])

p , e = optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y)
xd = np.linspace(-6, 28, 3000)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(xd, piecewise_linear(xd, *p))
plt.xticks(np.arange(-6.0,28.0, 2.0),rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,6,0.5))
```

2nd method:

```
import pwlf

x = np.array(n3.Lufttemperatur)

y = np.array(n3.id030_1)


my_pwlf = pwlf.PiecewiseLinFit(x, y)
breaks = my_pwlf.fit(2)
print(breaks)


x_hat = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
y_hat = my_pwlf.predict(x_hat)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(x_hat, y_hat, '-')
plt.xticks(np.arange(-6.0,28.0, 2.0),rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,6,0.5))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you trying to enforce that the first line segment have a negative slope, and the second line segment have a positive slope?

Answer (score 2):

**First method**:
when defining the second piecewise equation, instead of: `lambda x:k2*x + y0-k2*x0`
you should use: `lambda x:y0`

**Second method** consisting of using pwlf:

1- use pwlf to extract `x0` displayed as the second element in the breaks and the corresponding `y0`
2-use it in the piecewise equation, for instance of x0 = 9.5 and y0 = 36 :

```
np.piecewise(x, [x < 9.5], [lambda x:k1*x + 36-k1*9.5, lambda x:36])
```